# CouchDB directional replicaction FUTON

Tags: couchdb, replication, bidirectional

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 in a VMware and the same in a different physical machine, even using Hamachi. The thing is that I can replicate my DB using futon to the physical one but the physical one cannot replicate in the WMware.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include relevant commands you're using and the configuration for the databases.

Comment: had to configure the firewall and run it again, with futon there is no any code